# How to (if it's possible) configure relationship beetween a entity type with another that has no key field using Entity Framework Core fluent API

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Currently I'm work with a legacy database and need make relations between some SQL Server tables. The problem is the database model has no primary keys in some tables, but have related data with others.

Using fluent I configure the map class to entity/table B with:

```
builder.HasNoKey();
```

And in map class to entity/table A:

```
builder.HasMany(m => m.TableB).WithOne(o => o.TableA).HasForeignKey(fk => fk.ColumnKey);
```

But, I continue to get a error about TableB that has no key really (TableA has a PK), and is necessary to use `HasNoKey()` to configure it. So, how I can create a relationship between those tables?

Comment: If you tell EF that table B does have a primary key it'll believe you.

Comment: Yes, I tryed this, but unfortunately not works. Thanks